# What's the best/fastest way to get the count of tiff tags from a tif image with LibTiff.Net?

Tags: c#, tags, tiff, libtiff.net

Just as stated in the title, what is the best and fastest way to get the count of tiff tags in an image?

Currently the only way I know of is trying to query tags 1-65534 using the GetField() method and simply counting that way.  Is there some type of array or list of tags that I can access from the Tiff object in the LibTiff.Net library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current approach is the only one available through API. So, obviously, it's the fastest one.

`Tiff` class maintains internal representation of current image directory (page). This information contains all found tags. But probably it's not worth the hassle to try to get to that information.

Comment: OK thanks!  Then is there a way to see if there are tags already written to the tiff?  I need to see if I should use a rewrite or just check directory method...  My main goal here is to find out if there are tags written at all.  should I keep doing it the way I'm currently doing it?

Comment: In your case you might just check for presence of "required" (used in any file) tags. I *guess* that if any of `IMAGEWIDTH`, `IMAGELENGTH`, `BITSPERSAMPLE`, `STRIPOFFSETS`, `TILEOFFSETS`, `SAMPLESPERPIXEL` is not NULL or zero than there are tags already placed in a file.